# Connect Angular Material Table with a simple array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular-material

Today i'm in big trouble in order to use angular material table. I don't understand everything...
I would like to connect my AngularApp with a robot that send me information in a "datas" array.
I did like that to show my array:

```
<table id="sensorsTable" class="table table-striped">
<tr *ngFor="let data of datas">
    <td>{{data.name}}</td>
    <td>{{data.value}}</td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

This was working fine but I would like to use Angular Material table

Here is my typescript code and my view doen't change when my array "datas" is changing...

If someone can help me !

here is the actual typescript code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var Robot: any;
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';




export interface Data {
  name: string;
  value: number
}

var datas: Data[] = [
  {name: 'Hydrogen', value: 1.0079},
  {name: 'Helium', value: 4.0026},
  {name: 'Lithium', value: 6.941},
  {name: 'Beryllium', value: 9.0122},
  {name: 'Boron', value: 10.811},
  {name: 'Carbon', value: 12.0107},
];

export class MyDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  /** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing the data to render. */
  connect(): Observable<Data[]> {
    return Observable.of(datas);
  }

  disconnect() {}
}
@Component({
  selector: 'roomba-app',
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styles: ["./app.component.scss"]
}) 
export class AppComponent  { 
  datas: Array<Object> = [];
  robot:any;
  powerMotorRight: number;
  powerMotorLeft: number;
  maxSpeed = 200;

  displayedColumns = ['name', 'value'];
  dataSource = new MyDataSource();

  @HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
  handleKeyPressed(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    let keyPressed = event.key;
    if(keyPressed == "z"){
      this.powerMotorRight = this.maxSpeed;
      this.powerMotorLeft = this.maxSpeed;
    }
    if(keyPressed == "s"){
      this.powerMotorRight = -this.maxSpeed;
      this.powerMotorLeft = -this.maxSpeed;
    }
    if(keyPressed == "d"){
      this.powerMotorLeft = this.maxSpeed;
      this.powerMotorRight = -this.maxSpeed;
    }
    if(keyPressed == "q"){
      this.powerMotorLeft = -this.maxSpeed;
      this.powerMotorRight = this.maxSpeed;
    }

    this.robot.fullMode();
    this.robot.driveDirect(this.powerMotorRight, this.powerMotorLeft);
    console.log("KeyPressed: " + keyPressed);
  }

  @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
  handleKeyUp(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    let keyUp = event.key;
    this.powerMotorLeft = 0;
    this.powerMotorRight = 0;
    this.robot.stop();
    console.log("KeyUp: " + keyUp);
  }



  constructor(){
    let testData = {
      name: "test",
      value: "255"
    };
    this.datas.push(testData);

    this.robot = new Robot();

    //On connection to the server
    this.robot.on("connected", function(){
        console.log("connected");
        //We put roomba in safemode
        this.robot.safeMode();
        //And ask him to stream all sensors
        this.robot.streamAllSensors();
        //this.robot.changeInterval(50);
        this.robot.fullMode();
        this.robot.driveDirect(200,200);


        // setTimeout(function(){
        //   this.robot.fullMode();
        //   this.robot._sendCommand([137,0,127,0,1,157,0,87, 137, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
        //   console.log("test");
        // }.bind(this), 1000);

        // setInterval(function(){
        //   this.robot.getDistance();
        //   console.log("distance refresh");
        // }.bind(this), 10000);
      }.bind(this));

      //On data update
    this.robot.on("datas", function(receivedDatas:any){
        //Update the model
        this.datas = receivedDatas;
        datas = this.datas;    
    }.bind(this));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of datas | async">
```

Comment: A bit more explanation would've been nice.